# Callback liqpay возвращает 500 ошибку

Tags: php, laravel, платежи, liqpay

Отправляю запрос в liqpay, человек оплачивает и все ок.

```
$public_key  = 'public_key';
        $private_key = 'private_key';
        $params = array(
            'version' => '3',
            'action' => 'pay',
            'amount' => '1',
            'currency' => 'UAH',
            'description' => 'опис',
            'public_key'=> $public_key,
            'language' => 'uk',
            'order_id' => time(),
            'server_url' => 'url/checkpayment'
        );
```

После, приходит через server_url callback c signature и data.
Я их могу сохранить в файл, а в liqpay отобразиться код 200(все прошло успешно).

Но как только я пытаюсь через **base64_** расшифровать data или закодировать для сравнения signature, то ничего не происходит и в Liqpay 500-я ошибка.

Думал проблема с memory_limit в php или с кэшем на сервере, решил протестировать просто отправить внутри сайта post запрос с data и в post'е её раскодировать *dd(json_decode(base64_decode($request->all('data'))));*
Все прошло на отлично.
Теперь не понятно почему когда именно от liqpay приходит такой же запрос, то возвращает 500-ю ошибка.
Что не так с этим **base64_decode/base64_encode** ??

```
if($request->isMethod('POST')){
            $all_signature = $request->all('signature');
            $all_data = $request->all('data');
            $sign = base64_encode( sha1(
                $this->private_key .
                $all_data .
                $this->private_key
                , 1 ));
            $parsed_data = json_decode(base64_decode($all_data));
            if($sign === $all_signature){
                echo "ok";
                Storage::disk('local')->put('333data.txt', $parsed_data);
                Storage::disk('local')->put('333sign.txt', $all_data);
            }else{
               echo "invalid signature: {$sign} != {$all_signature}";
            }
}
```

Comment: Логи смотрели? 500 обычно логируются с коробки в laravel

Comment: `Storage::disk('local')->put('333data.txt', $parsed_data);` возможно тут ошибка. Закомментируйте переменную  $parsed_data и попробуйте так `Storage::disk('local')->put('333data.txt', base64_decode($all_data));`. И лучше использовать only, вместо all `$request->only(['data'])`

Comment: 1. 500 не могу найти в логах.
2. Сделал все как вы и описали, результат тот же.

Comment: Почистил логи и на чистую запустил, то вот такое "local.ERROR: base64_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): base64_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given at"

Comment: Ну вот и ошибка.. Ожидается строка, а $all_data это массив

Comment: Так написано да, но там строка =(  Как тогда переделать в строку?
https://ibb.co/yQQZXXn

Comment: @Alex А с каких пор метод `$request->all('data')` стал возвращать конкретное поле? Или `$request->data`, или если уж методом хотите, то `$request->input('data')`. Отсюда и ошибка, что Вы ожидаете значение, а Вам возвращается массив со всеми данными реквеста.

Comment: Фух, все! Спасибо вам большое. Разобрался. Ну и ночка)